# How to verify a simple neural network? I want to convert the layers into mathematical equations and then use a solver for eg. SAT solver

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, verification, formal-verification, sat

I have seen many papers where they verify neural networks. Either they try to check adversarial robustness or finds an input that the model predicts incorrectly. They try to convert a layer to a mathematical equation for eg a boolean expression. And then solves it by available solvers (Microsoft Z3, Gurobi). But I could not find any tutorial or starting code.

Can you help me start the process? For example, share a code to convert one fully connected layer with ReLu activation for MNIST data. Then I can build on top of that for a more complex layer.

Thanks

Comment: Note that Z3 is an SMT solver; Gurobi is about mathematical optimization. To the best of my knowledge, formal verification of neural networks is a hot research topic today; consequently, you will find mostly research papers. Maybe you find [Darwiche's talks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6JFTkmPMfmI) talks interesting. I think they are based on SAT and #SAT

Comment: @tphilipp thanks for your correction. I will definitely watch the video. Can you explain the difference between solver and optimizer in terms of application?

Answer (score 1):

I'll give it a try. One way is to formulate the network structure as an integer linear program (ILP). Lets first consider the easier case with a linear activation. A fully connected layer with input **x** then has output **y** = W**x** + **b**,  where W is matrix of the weights of each neuron of the layer and **b** a vector of the biases.

Suppose the layer has input dimension *n* and output dimension *m*. In the ILP formulation we'll need to define a continuous variable for the layer inputs and outputs:

- x_i, for 0 <= i < n
- y_i, for 0 <= i < m.

We'll represent the values of the weights and biases of the layer with

- b_i, for 0 <= i < m
- W_ij, for 0 <= i < n and 0 <= j < m.

Then the output of the *i* th neuron can be encoded by the linear equation

y_i = b_i + W_i0*x_0 + W_i1*x_1 + ... W_in*x_n.

This should be straightforward to do with any ILP library (like CPLEX or Gurobi for example).
Encoding the ReLU nonlinearity is a bit more involved. One way to do it is as follows:

- Restrict variables y_i to positive values (ie set lower bound to 0)

This breaks the previous equation for the value of y_i when the right hand side of the equation is negative. To fix this, we'll add new variables

- s_i, for 0 <= i < m

and also set the lower bound on the value of each s_i to 0. We'll then reformulate the previous linear equation as

y_i - s_i = b_i + W_i0*x_0 + W_i1*x_1 + ... W_in*x_n.

This equation now allows for nonsense solutions, we still need to add a constraint which requires that one of y_i or s_i be equal to zero. The intuition behind this is that in y_i and s_i we split the value of the right hand side into a positive component y_i and a negative component s_i. Then y_i will be the value of the ReLU function and s_i can be ignored.

The implementation will depend on the specific library, but in CPLEX *indicator constraints* can be used. In short, we add *binary* variables

- z_i, for 0 <= i < m

as well as indicator constraints stating that

- if z_i = 0, then y_i = 0
- if z_i = 1, then s_i = 0

I implemented this some time back for a simple neural network using CPLEX in https://github.com/psaikko/explain-mnist/blob/master/twoclass/min_explanation.py. Lines 26-97 perform the encoding into ILP as explained above.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. In the equation: y_i = b_i + W_i0*x_0 + W_i1*x_1 + ... W_in*x_n, are all of my input(x), weights, and biases are variables? And solvers try to determine if there is a solution for y_i by randomly picking values of all the variables. Ami I thinking it right? Then how do I compare the verifiable accuracy of my trained model with this one? I want compare the accuracy of classification using this solvers with the trained model.

Comment: It would depend on your use case. For example if you want to compute adversarial examples for a pretrained network, then the weights and biases would be constants equal to the weights of that network. The input x then might be either variables representing the network input, or the output variables of a preceding layer.

Comment: @Paul you answer has been very helpful in my research, what is to adjust in case  the network had a non-linear activation

Comment: @FarabiAbdelwahed something like a sigmoid or tanh activation can't be used directly with this ILP approach. I'm not familiar with the current progress in this direction but found a [2018 paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7742-efficient-neural-network-robustness-certification-with-general-activation-functions.pdf) on verifying robustness properties with general activation functions which might be a starting point for looking further